# What are some approaches for pattern matching?

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching

How do different languages do pattern matching? In Rust it's

```rust
match x {
    y => ...,
    z => ...
}
```

However in ocaml it's

```ocaml
match x with
| y -> ...
| z -> ...
```

I'm wondering about some unique approaches to pattern matching.

Comment: The word "approaches" is vague; it could encompasses syntax, semantics and/or implementation details. The examples you've given are just different syntaxes and your question is tagged syntax, but the existing answers have mostly focused on semantics. I think the question would be improved if it asked specifically about semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern matching syntax is somewhat uniform across languages. Sometimes you'll see `if`/`else` with single patterns, which may look like `if let Some(x) = y {}` (Rust), `if(Some(var x) is y) {}` (C#) or some variation of this.

Meanwhile,

## Egison

[Egison](https://www.egison.org/) is a language that qualifies itself as *Pattern-Match-Oriented*.
An extensive SE answer would require to copy/paste Egi's entire thesis, so I'll try to summarise some interesting features.

```
def twinPrimes :=
    matchAll primes as list integer with
        | _ ++ $p :: #(p + 2) :: _ -> (p, p + 2)

take 6 twinPrimes
-- [(3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31), (41, 43)]
```

As you can see here, there exists a basic language that should be familiar (`matchAll xs with <pattern> -> <expr>`), however

- Matching expressions may return one or *multiple* matches (`match` and `matchAll`, as do RegEx+),
- Patterns may be self-referential (`$p :: #(p + 2)` matches `0, 2` but not `1, 2`),
- *Matchers* (the `as list integer` part above) are **user-defined** relations between the input and output.

This last point in particular allows to specify arbitrary matching strategies.
Here is an example of a pattern match ignoring the order of pairs:

```
def unorderedPair m :=
    matcher
        | ($, $) as (m, m) with
            | ($x, $y) -> [(x, y), (y, x)]
        | $ as (eq) with
            | $x -> [$x]
```

which can be used as

```
matchAll (2, 5) as unorderedPair with
    | (#5, $x) -> x
```

resulting in `2` due to the `(#5, $x)` branch attempting both possible order and succeeding with one.

## Active Patterns

[F#'s Active Patterns](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Active_Patterns) are a another pattern matching language where the matching logic is user-defined in functions with funky names like `(|Even|Odd|)`, which may furthermore be *parametrised*.
In those names, essentially each possible branch is named after the bar-separated identifiers.

For example,

```fs
let (|Even|Odd|) n =
    if n % 2 = 0 then
        Even
    else
        Odd

do
    match 42 with
        | Even -> printfn "success"
        | Odd -> printfn "?"
```

Those functions being parametrisable allow to define arbitrary sublanguages, such as,

```fs
type MSpec<'a> =
    | Req of 'a
    | Opt of 'a

//xs is our parameter, ys is what we match against
let (|M|_|)<'a when 'a : equality> (xs: MSpec<'a> list) (ys: 'a list) =
    let rec f (xs': MSpec<'a> list) (ys': 'a list) =
        match xs' with
        | [] ->
            List.isEmpty ys'
        | (Opt xhd) :: xtl ->
            match ys' with
            | yhd :: ytl ->
                if xhd = yhd then
                    f xtl ytl
                else
                    f xtl ys'
            | _ ->
                f xtl ys'
        | (Req xhd) :: xtl ->
            match ys' with
            | yhd :: ytl -> 
                if xhd = yhd then
                    f xtl ytl
                else
                    false
            | _ ->
                false
    in
    if f xs ys then Some () else None
```

```fs
let g = function
| M [Opt 1; Req 2; Req 3] -> printfn "matches\n"
| _ -> printfn "nop\n"

do
    g [1; 2; 3] //matches
    g [2; 3]    //matches
    g [4; 2; 3] //nop
```

which should be reminiscent of RegExp's `1?23`, and where a name with an underscore branch (`(|M|_|)`) uses Some/None.

Answer (score 3):

### Repurpose `switch`

This is what Swift does. From [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/controlflow#Where):

> ```swift
> let yetAnotherPoint = (1, -1)
> switch yetAnotherPoint {
> case let (x, y) where x == y:
>     print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == y")
> case let (x, y) where x == -y:
>     print("(\(x), \(y)) is on the line x == -y")
> case let (x, y):
>     print("(\(x), \(y)) is just some arbitrary point")
> }
> // Prints "(1, -1) is on the line x == -y"
> ```

In terms of the implementation, pattern matching calls the operator `~=`.

However, Swift only lets you destructure tuples and enums, not structs. TSPL has [a patterns chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/patterns) that lists all the valid patterns.

Answer (score 3):

A unique pattern matching approach is the idris2/idris [with rule](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/views.html).

The unique feature is that the item being matched is viewed as an added argument of the function, and when matching/destructing this "argument", *the "existing/original arguments" can be affected as well*. Here is an example function from the above documentation for converting a natural number to its binary representation (as a list of Bool's):

```
natToBin : Nat -> List Bool
natToBin Z = Nil
natToBin k with (parity k)
   natToBin (j + j)     | Even = False :: natToBin j
   natToBin (S (j + j)) | Odd  = True  :: natToBin j
```

where the parity of k (`parity k`) is matched (either `Even` or `Odd`). What's special is that depending on whether `parity k` is `Even` or `Odd`, the existing argument `k` is also refined/changed to `j + j` (when `Even`) or `1 + j + j` (when `Odd`). This is different from most languages where you match a variable/expression by itself.

Additional details and definitions are in the documentation linked above.

Answer (score 1):

### Pattern matching in Papyri

[Papyri](https://kaya3.github.io/papyri) is a dynamically-typed pure-functional programmable markup language which compiles to HTML. (Disclosure: I am the author of Papyri.)

The main things distinguishing Papyri from other languages are that the syntax is constrained to mostly be a superset of HTML, and HTML content (tags, text, and sequences) is a first-class data type, so the pattern-matching has to support it.

A [pattern match expression](https://kaya3.github.io/papyri/tutorial.html#pattern_matching) in Papyri looks like this:

```
@match scrutinee {
    pattern1 -> branch1,
    pattern2 -> branch2,
    # ...
}
```

This is broadly similar to matching in other languages:

- It's an expression so it results in a value and each branch must be an expression.
- Patterns are in order of priority, so if more than one pattern could match then the earliest one is used.
- A pattern can bind names to values extracted from the scrutinee, which are then in scope within the branch associated with that pattern.
- Since it's a dynamic language, there is no static check to ensure the patterns are exhaustive; it's an error at runtime if the scrutinee doesn't match any of them.
- "Or" patterns; `pattern1 | pattern2` is a pattern which matches if either of the sub-patterns matches ─ again, in order of priority.
- "Spread" patterns; for example, `[$head, *$tail]` matches a list with at least one element.

Some more unusual things about pattern-matching in Papyri:

- HTML tag patterns, like `<$tag_name id=$id> $body </>`. This would match a tag of any name, with an `id` attribute and no other attributes, and any contents; these would be bound to the variables `$tag_name`, `$id` and `$body` respectively, but they could be arbitrary other patterns.
- HTML content patterns, like `{Hello, <span>$name</span>!}`. This would match an HTML sequence consisting of the text `"Hello, "`, a span tag with no attributes and any contents, and the text `"!"`.
- Equality patterns, like `=$x`. This matches if the value equals the result of the given expression. The expression may use variables which are bound already by other parts of the same pattern.
- "And" patterns, like `pattern1 & pattern2`. This matches if both patterns individually match; it is useful for things like `$x & [$a, $b, $c]`, where you want to bind a list to the name `$x` while also binding its members to other names.